# php move sub-array foreach to function in event calendar display

Tags: php, arrays, function, nested, sub-array

To retrieve data from an API, am using a php library which returns an Object containing the unordered event information.

Each event returns boolean value for each day of the week (Monday, Tues, etc).

Thinking the idea is to:

1. Iterate object and test each event for Weekday (Sun, Mon, etc)
   If TRUE

   1. create and populate an array of required details for the event
   2. create and populate an array of Event arrays for the Weekday
   3. sort each Weekday by event time
   4. Display days events

Right now am using:

```
if ($class->DaySunday == 1) 
{   //initialize or increment counter
!isset($num_classes) ? $num_classes = 0 : $num_classes++;
//assemble Class details into array containing the day name
$single_class = build_class('sunday',$class,$num_classes);
//Create and populate @Day Schedule with Single Class arrays 
foreach ($single_class as $class => $details)
    $sunday_schedule[$num_classes][$class] = $details;
//Sort the Day Schedule by Hour, earliest to latest
usort($sunday_schedule, "sortFunction");
} 
if ($class->DayMonday == 1) {}//etc...
```

Where build_class() returns an array for each class:

```
function build_class($day_name,$class,$num_classes)
{
//Create and populate @Single Class details from ClassSchedule Object 
$single_class['Class Name'] = $class->ClassDescription->Name;
return $single_class;
}
```

It seems like either creating the array of event arrays for each day should be able to happen in the same function that creates the array for each class, but I cannot seem to make it work because it either creates a giant array of events from every day OR overwrites events so that each day is left with only one event.

Having the above five lines of code repeated for each IF_is_particular_weekday function is ugly and there must be a more effective way. Do I need to build the name of each Day array dynamically?

Am not even sure if creating arrays from the object is the most effective approach in the first place.

So in other words:

dynamically generating the variable name no. add the array to another array. so @the week contains @the days contain @the classes:

```
Array (
    [monday] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [Class Name] => Work Out
            [Instructor] => General Meany
        )
    [tuesday] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [Class Name] => Dance
            [Instructor] => Ballerina
        )
    )
)
```

This is my first stackoverflow post and I welcome (and fear) your insights. -thanks.

This is the call and function:

```
if ($class->DaySunday == 1) 
{//initialize or increment counter for specific day
!isset($sun_class_count) ? $sun_class_count = 0 : $sun_class_count++;
$day_name = 'Sunday';
//send Day, Object, Day Count and class and day arrays to build week function
$week_schedule = build_week($day_name,$class,$sun_class_count,$single_class,$week_schedule);
} 
if ($class->DayMonday == 1)
{!isset($mon_class_count) ? $mon_class_count = 0 : $mon_class_count++;
$day_name = 'Monday';}//etc

function build_week($day_name,$class,$class_count,$single_class,$week_schedule)
{
//Create and populate @Single Class details from ClassSchedule Object 
    $single_class['Class Name'] = $class->ClassDescription->Name;
    $single_class['Instructor'] = $class->Staff->Name; 
    $single_class['Class Type'] = $class->ClassDescription->SessionType->Name; 
$single_class['Start Time'] = $class->StartTime;  
$single_class['End Time'] = $class->EndTime;  
$single_class['Day Name'] = $day_name; 
$week_schedule[$day_name][$class_count] =  $single_class;

return $week_schedule;          }
```

Comment: Thanks much for the clarification @Gordon. Final code is simple, of course.

Comment: can't seem to get code to display in comments. will edit above once i have sorted sorting the times of day. (using usort, i think)

Comment: Got a great, simple method for sorting the 2nd nested array based on a value within the 3rd nested array in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188589/sort-2nd-nested-array-by-value-in-3rd-with-php